# How do I initialize a struct in a Class constructor list?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to initialize a struct within a default class initializer list. For example, if I have a class like like this:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    somestruct p;
public:
    Foo(): x(1), y(2), z(3)
    {
        // other stuff
    }
};
```

So, I can clearly initialize primitive types this way - how do I initialize a struct, for example the `somestruct p` parameter? Are there any limitations on the design of `p` if initialized this way?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code? I'm not really able to visualize this.

Comment: Show code, or its rather difficult to understand exactly what you're after.

Comment: This question is very poorly constructed. Please make more of an effort.

Comment: Call the struct's constructor, just like any other type. Or are you referring specifically to _aggregate_ initialization?

Comment: @Abdul I've edited your question to include what I *think* you're referring to - if that's not right, can you please edit the question again to provide a clearer example? That way we know exactly what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code below, `m_strct` is a member of `MyClass`, and is initialized by the default constructor.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(int i): // Constructor
        myData(i)
    { }

    int myData;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() :  // default constructor
        m_strct(0)
    { }

private:    
    MyStruct m_strct;
};
```

Comment: Oops, I wrote it more as a C# answer, when it shoulda been C++.  Thanks to @ildjarn for fixing me up.